# Getting interpolated normal from barycentric coordinate

Tags: interpolation, mesh, cgal

I'm new to CGAL and have never used a heavily templated library like this before so I'm struggling to understand how I can get an interpolated normal from barycentric coordinates on a Surface Mesh.

I have a Surface_mesh with a normal property_map, and I'm looking to get the interpolated normal at a specific barycentric coordinate on it (using Face_location and the location methods in Polygon_mesh_processing). I have seen interpolation related topics in the docs but can't really make sense of it.

Thanks !

PS : I'm using CGAL because it's the only library I could find that had location methods (get the barycentric on a mesh from a point in space and such). If there is a simpler library than offers this I might be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you simply have to take the normals of the 3 vertices of the face and do the weighted sum of the normals using the barycentric coordinates you got when you call the locate function.

See [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__locate__grp.html#ga35604eae6b378b8254a3f41f1a274b9e) for how to related the weight to the correct face vertex (thus normal).

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't realize barycentric coordinates were enough to interpolate the values :)